# Chanting Devi Mahathyam (Durga Saptashati)

Tags: practice, worship, durga, chandipath

I would like to chant the Devi Mahathyam but may not be able to do the full text together in a single sitting or in a day. So if I am to split the chapters across days, are there any prescribed format for it?

I assume each day I will start with Argala, Keelaka and Kavacham followed by some chapters, say max 3 per day. What all should be chanted post the chapters daily?

Are there existing rules for this to be chanted as a Saptaha or in 9 days etc?

Comment: This book for SaptaShati -
[SaptaShati](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://mridarbhanga.bih.nic.in/religious%2520books/Durga_Saptashati.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi4j9jV6rvZAhXLGZQKHaHuD2sQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw234NYV3cgYjh-aiTlpCygq) , describes how to do paath. But there is a very huge sankalpa which says "I will read it from beginning to end". So it is suggested that do not read that Sankalp, and just ask Mother Chandika - "O Parvati! I will read 3 Chapters today. Thou art mother of all so bless me."

Comment: The book provided above, contains part of Sanskrit shloka and Hindi translation on each page. So it is better to read just 1 chapter in one day, but do it by reading both Sanskrit and Hindi translation. (Because reading SaptaShati without understanding it is almost of no use). The Book provided above contains a lot lot Karma Kaanda of Navarna Jaapa, Nyaasa  , RahasyaPaath , so do it after guidance of some real Guru or Pujaari. Or else, better just read Siddha Kunjika Stotra once before and once after the SaptaShati paath, and ask for blessings of Devi and Shiva. Ask them to give you real Guru.

Comment: Are the prayers listed in Patavidhi (before the actual chapters) and Upasamhara (After the chapters) needed daily? I had anyway planned on Kavacham, Argala and Keelakam. Would like to know about the rest

Comment: I have gone through the book  and it is written that you need to do daily. This is why either do the long PaathaVidhi , Upasanhaara et cetera, under guidance of some Guru. Or you can just Chant Siddha Kunjika Stotra once before and once after the Praath. In sidhha Kunjika Shiva said - "O Devi! No need to chant Argala, Kavach or Keelak. Only Chanting Kunjika Stotra is enough." So better just do simple Chanting for now. Reading Devi SaptaShati with devotion and simplicity is better than Engaging in complicated rituals.

Comment: More important is your understanding the essence and beauty of SaptaShati and your devotion to Devi. Also at the end of daily paath ask for forgiveness in your own words- "O Mother! I do not know the long rituals neither long Mantras neither long Vidhis. But I know only you and you are refuge to all world. O Devi! Take this all paath whatever I could do and bless me." भक्तिहीनं क्रियाहीनं मन्त्रहीनं सुरेश्वरि । यत्पूजितं मया देवि परिपूर्णम् तदस्तु मे ॥ (this is only an example, it need not be in Sanskrt. Can be in your own language) .

Comment: You can split the book and complete in three or seven or nine days. Many people in South India follow it. Dont feel anything wrong about it

Answer (score 6):

Some basic rules-

Each chapter should be read in single sitting. Due to any reason, if parayana is stopped in between a chapter; then the whole chapter should be read again.
**इति , वध , समाप्त , अध्याय** these must be avoided at any cost while concluding Chapter.
Instead one can say,
" श्री मार्कण्डेयपुराणे सावर्णिके मंन्वंतरे देविमाहात्म्ये प्रथमः/द्वितीयः/त्रयोदाशः" (Depending on chapter number)
Bhuttashuddi, Asaansuddhi, Chittasuddhi, etc must be done on before hand of sankalpa itself.

```
Are the prayers listed in Patavidhi (before the actual chapters) and Upasamhara (After the chapters) needed daily?
```

Yes.

The order of reciting Durga Saptashati Parayana daily is: Anga Mantra Krama, Navakshari Chandi Mantra, Devi Mahatmya. Again Navakshari Chandi mantra in end of every chapter with Devi Suktam & Siddh Kunjika Stotram.

```
 I had anyway planned on Kavacham, Argala and Keelakam. Would like to know about the rest.
```

So continuing from the previously told thing. This will explain your all doubts in detail.

1. ANGA STOTRA-

There are numerous methods of Anga recitations before Devi Mahatmyam – Trayangam (3), Navangam(9), Dashangam(10), Dwadashanga(12), and it reaches upto 56 Angas. But, these highest Anga are reserved for established sadhakas.

Let us discuss 3,9,10 limbs here.

• **त्रयंग पारायणविधिह्**

In Tryanga Parayana, three limbs are recited before parayana of Shree Chandi.
One must chant Devi Kavacham, Argala Stotram and Devi Keelakam and then start Shree Chandi parayana if done by Trayanga Vidhi.

(Usually Trayangam is considered incomplete by some Shaktas, because of absence of some fundamentals like Nyas, Avahan, etc.)

• **नवांग पारायणविधिह्**

> न्यासमावाहनं चैव नामान्यर्गलकीलकम्।
> हृदयं च दलं चैव ध्यानं कवचमेव च।।
> महात्म्यं च जपेन्नित्यमष्टम्यां च विशेषतः।
> सौभाग्यं च लभेन्नित्यं नरो मुच्यते संकटात्।।
> Devi Nyasa, Avahana & Namani, Argala Stotram, Keelaka, Hrudayam, Dala & Dhyana, Kavacha.
> Those who read mahatmya daily this way, or on Ashtami especially, those men gain good fortune & are delivered from miseries.

(Moslty for nyas all Ekadasha Nyasas are included.)

Thus, one must recite these 9 limbs and Navakshari chandi mantra & then do Parayana.

• **दशांग पारायणविधिह् (हरगौरीतंत्रम्)**

> न्यासो ध्यानावाहने च नामसूक्तम चाप्यनु।
> दलं च हृदयम चैव कवचार्गलाकिलकम्।।
> दशांगानि च जप्तवा तु पश्चात्सप्ताशतीम् पठेत्।।
> Devi Nyas, Dhyaan, Avahanam, Naam, Suktam with Dala, Hrudyam & Kavach, Argala, Kilakam stotras. This way after reciting the 10 limbs, one must read Saptashati.

Shree Bhaskararaya has his own thoughts on this, Bhaskararaya consider that Kavach, Argala, Keelak, Navarna mantra jaap & Ratri Suktam these Purva Panchangas (first 5 limbs) must be recited before path parayana & Devi Suktam, Navarna jaap & the Rahasyas tarayam these Uttar Panchangas (last 5 limbs )must be chanted after Parayana. Thus, completing total Dashanga Parayana (10 limbs). This is considered as Dashamga-yut-Krama.
(PS - This Krama given by Bhaskararaya is followed by most Saptashati books available in market. As this is in accordance with Marichi tantra too.)

2. DEVI MAHATMYA PARAYANA

Various Kramas are in fashion to do Shree Chandi Parayana, like Mahavidya Krama, Nikumbala Krama, Beejakshar Krama, Maha-Chandi Krama, Yogini, Ratnadeepika krama, etc. And each krama is as powerful as other.
To say in few words about these Kramas, in each of these kramas the chapter sequences are changed. For eg. in Mahavidya Krama & Chandi Krama chapters are read frm Pratham, Madhyam & Uttar Chatira (1-13) in sequence. While in Mahachandi Krama the chapters are read in reverse order Uttar, Madhyam & then Pratham Charitra (13-1).
(Commonly people use Mahavidya Krama or Chandi krama thus, reading chapters 1 to 13 in a sequence.)

```
So if I am to split the chapters across days, are there any prescribed format for it?
```

Coming to how to read a particular fashion in a number of days.
Devi mahatmya's complete parayana can be done in 1, 3, 7, 9 days, depending on time & capacity of Sadhaka.
(Here we are discussing on Mahavidya Krama or Chandi Krama of recitation. Which is most common as I said earlier.)

• Ek divsiya Parayana (1 day)
The complete Parayana with all three charitras & anga mantras, etc must be done in a single day.

• Traya divsiya Parayana (3 days)
3 Charitras are recited in three days. This is traya divsiya krama.
Prathama Charitra or 1st Chapter on first day, Madhyama Charitra (2, 3, 4 chapters) on 2nd day, and Uttama Charitra (5-13 chapters) on third day.

• Sapta Divasiya Parayana (7 days)
The complete Saptashati is read in 7 days.
1st Chapter on first day, 2-3 chapters on 2nd day, 4thchapter on 3rd day, 5-8 chapters on 4th day, 9-10 chapters on 5th day, 11th chapter on 6th day and 12-13 chapters on 7th day.

• Navdivsiya Krama (9 days, Mostly used in Navaratri)
1st day: Chapter 1 (Madhu kaitabha samhaara)
2nd day: Chapter 2, 3 and 4 (Mahishhasura samhaara)
3rd day: Chapter 5 and 6 (Dhuumralochana vadha)
4th day: Chapter 7 (Chanda Munda vadha)
5th day: Chapter 8 (Rakta biija samhaara)
6th day: Chapter 9 and 10 (Shumbha Nishumbha vadha)
7th day: Chapter 11 (Praise of Narayani)
8th day: Chapter 12 (Phalastuti – reciting merits or benefits)
9th day: Chapter 13 (Blessings to Suratha and the Merchant)
10th day: Completion of Parayana with Nyas & respective Suktas.

But, the basic problem here is that till 9 days the parayana continues, and Chandi yagna which is usually done on the completion of parayana, will be scheduled on the 9th day, with Kanya & Vipra pujan. Also, additional stotrams like Rahasya trayam, Chandi Aavran puja, Suktams, concluding nyasas, etc must be done on the very same day. Which becomes too hectic to be completed in a single day. Because, this in addition to the nitya puja of the devi established in ghaatam. Thus usually people do Sapta divsiya 7 days parayana, with Yagna & Avaran & concluding nyas pujas on Mahashtami, Kshma & Shanti anushthan with Kanya & Vipra puja on Mahanavami or vice-versa (Altough Shanti anushthans happen on Navami always).

Since, the rituals are way elobarative one must truly surrender to guru to learn this.

I hope this answer help true upasakas of Bhagwati Paramba.
But, I must say this, that, Saptashati is the quicksand of mysteries, the deeper you go to find the secrets of Saptashati, the more you will pulled in. There is no one who can completely tell Saptashati's greatness or even it's complete parayana vidhi, because no one could ever completely the understand the greatness of the charitras of Chandika.

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**